# Generating bounding boxes if I have the text labels and co-ordinates of bounding boxes

Tags: conv-neural-network, object-detection, opencv3.0, bounding-box

I am trying to implement the Convolutional character network or CharNet model
https://github.com/MalongTech/research-charnet

But I want to generate the bounding boxes in the images, but int he results I have only the co-ordinates and the character labels
[image]

Like the example above, so how can I generate the bounding boxes. Please help me out here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use cv2.rectangle(), or google something else like any other library (like PIL) you are comfortable with

Comment: But there are 8 co-ordinates here, how to get bounding boxes now

Comment: You can check the documentation of the repo to find out what the 8 coordinates suggest or plot points, 8 values are likely for x and y coordinates of 4 points, out of which you have to find out which belongs to which and what your rectangle function needs